# How can I do cross-domain postMessage?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, postmessage

The documentation for [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) implies that cross-domain messaging is possible. However:

```
// When the popup has fully loaded, if not blocked by a popup blocker
```

That isn't a very clear note of **how** to actually do it.

Imagine two websites:

1. [Parent] hosted on `qc-a.nfshost.com`
2. [Child] hosted on `qc-b.quadhome.com`

In the parent:

```
document.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  alert('Parent got (from ' + e.origin + '): ' + e.data);

  e.source.postMessage('Round-tripped!', 'http://qc-b.quadhome.com');
}, false);

function go() {
  var w = window.open('http://qc-b.quadhome.com', 'test');

  /* This doesn't work because same-origin policy prevents knowing when
     the opened window is ready. */

  w.postMessage('Vain attempt.', 'http://qc-b.quadhome.com');
}
```

And, in the child:

```
document.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  alert('Child got (from ' + e.origin + '): ' + e.data);
}, false);

window.opener.postMessage('Ready!', 'http://qc-a.nfshost.com');
```

All to no avail.

Help?

Comment: Hi! `window.opener` is null, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, I am seeing two issues. Slight error in the code and the timeout issue.

1) The error I am seeing in your code is that you're using document.addEventListener. I think the right one is window.addEventListener. It is in the example on the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) page.

2) With the timeout, you can have the child window postMessage to the parent. The parent window will then know when the child is ready.

Comment: In short, I'm an idiot. Replaced `document` with `window` and the ready callback worked via `window.opener.postMessage`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the window & posting the message after each other. There's no way the open document will be ready to accept the post message. Try delaying the postMessage call until the window has finished loading.

A very simple way to test this is to wrap w.postMessage() in a setTimeout (for 10 seconds) and see if it can post it when the document is ready.

Comment: Right. The comment in the code mentions that there's no way (that I know) to know when the window is ready. And a 10 second timeout seems a bit... hacky.

Notice in the child window, I try to do a postMessage indicating readiness back up to the opener. That fails as well. Thoughts?