# postMessage() cross-origin iframe javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I am trying to communicate with cross-origin resources using postMessage(), but am unable to get it to work properly. I have reviewed dozens of other similar questions, but am still stuck.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage, https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication, [How can I do cross-domain postMessage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332532/how-can-i-do-cross-domain-postmessage), etc.)

I have this working on the same origin, but when I move to a different origin, I get a standard corss-origin error.

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin ... from accessing
> a cross-origin frame.

I call postMessage() twice. Once on page load using the wildcard - which is working. And once using a delcared origin - which is what I need, but can't get to work.

Parent:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button class="site-btn" onclick="initChatIfr();">Load Iframe</button>
        <iframe lws-ifr="demo-ifr" lws-ifr-status='inactive'></iframe>
    <script>
        const ifrEle = document.querySelector('[lws-ifr="chat-ifr"]');
        function initChatIfr() {
            ifrEle.src = 'https://some-cdn.cloudfront.net/post-message/index.html';
            ifrEle.setAttribute('lws-ifr-status', 'active');
        }

        function listener(e) {
            const acceptedOrigins = ['https://some-cdn.cloudfront.net', 'https://some-sandbox.s3.amazonaws.com', 'http://localhost:3000'];
            
            if (e.data.indexOf('close') < 0 || acceptedOrigins.indexOf(e.origin) < 0) {
                console.log('   not a close event or an unapproved ifr origin')
                return;
            } else {
                console.log(' approved ifr origin')
                ifrEle.setAttribute('lws-ifr-status', 'inactive');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    ifrEle.src = '';
                },300);                    
            }
        }

        if (window.addEventListener){
            addEventListener("message", listener, false);
        } else {
            attachEvent("onmessage", listener);
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Child:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button class="site-btn cancel-btn" onclick="closeParentIframe();">Close Iframe</button>
    <script>
        const acceptedHosts = ['some-cf-cdn.cloudfront.net', 'some-sandbox-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com', 'localhost:3000'];
        function closeParentIframe() {
            const pOrigin = parent.origin;
            const pHost = parent.location.host;
            if (acceptedHosts.indexOf(pHost) > -1) {
                console.log(' APPROVED parent origin', pOrigin);
                parent.postMessage('close', pOrigin);
            } else {
                console.log(' UNAPPROVED parent origin', pOrigin);
            }
        }
        console.log('ifr loaded');
        parent.postMessage("hi from the ifr " + location.href, '*');
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in your child script, you are trying to access `parent.origin` as well as `parent.location.host` which is causing the error because it's not allowed given the cross-origin concerns.

If you want to get the domain of the parent from the child code, you can instead use `document.location.ancestorOrigins[0`. However, it seems like this is currently not supported on any version Firefox (updated 2022). See https://caniuse.com/?search=ancestorOrigin

Other than that, the rest looks okay.

Here's a thread about options how to get the parent's domain from the iFrame: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52399194/14264568

Comment: Thank You - postMessage doesn't just turn off all cross-origin safeguards.   Implemented solution: Capture the click event => onclick="closeParentIframe(event);".   From that obtain the origin => const pOrigin = clickEvent.view.location.origin